# Passing a `refetch` to a Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I am trying to pass a refetch from a `useQuery()` into a context so that I can call the refetch from within the context. I haven't been able to figure out the correct type so I either run into a type mismatch issue, or the IDE doesn't complain but the app breaks on a type mismatch. When the browser crashes it reports that `refetch()` is not a function.

I'd just like to pass refetch into the Context and be able to call it. Any help is appreciated.

[IDE typings error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VADG.png)

Here is the related code:

The interface for the Context props:

```
interface ConfirmationModalContextInterface {
   ...
   setRefetch: (refetch: (variables?: Record<string, any>) => Promise<ApolloQueryResult<any>>) => void;
}
```

The interface for the Context confirmation modal:

```
interface ConfirmationModalProps {
   ...
   refetch: (variables?: Record<string, any>) => Promise<ApolloQueryResult<any>> | undefined;
}
```

The original `refetch` instance:

```
const {loading, error, data, refetch} = useQuery(queries.USER_POSTS);
```

The setting of the props for the context:

```
const confirmModalContext = useContext(ConfirmationModalContext);
const {..., setRefetch} = confirmModalContext;

setRefetch(refetch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates, `refetch` may be undefined but your interface doesn't take that into account. That said, it's not necessary to pass the `refetch` function around like this -- just reuse the same `useQuery` hook inside whatever component you need it. You can use the same `useQuery` hook throughout multiple components without triggering multiple requests.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. How would I use the same useQuery hook throughout multiple components without triggering multiple requests?

Comment: That is the default behavior for Apollo Client, unless you explicitly change the `fetchPolicy` to something like `network-only`. Provided it's the same query and same variables, it will only ever be fetched once -- subsequent requests will be fulfilled from the cache. Likewise, if two or more components initially request the same query at the same time, it will only be sent to the server once.